Subgrid won't display on basic form (Power Pages, Dataverse)
Basic form has a subgrid to enter data inside of it (it is data to be inserted into another table view). In the basic form designer and page preview in Microsoft Power Pages it shows up (including the add record button).
In the preview page however the other form fields show up besides the subgrid. In the table which the subgrid is connected to I have also created a record because it said somewhere it would need a main record but that still has not fixed the issue. In the subgrid properties there are no specific options to enable permissions nor to set it up as create, edit or detlete functions. I am new to Power Pages and Dataverse as well but as hard as I searched and tried various online solutions it still seems it does not want to work.

If you're doing a Preview of the 'Create' page then the subgrid is never displayed. For a subgrid to appear, the parent record must be saved first. Try to preview an 'Edit' page

consider two things :

adding Subgrid Metadata for your main form (EntityForm)
User permission for read/create on the subgrid table

